# Calculate the sum of all numbers from 1 to a given number using for loop (Also pls tell me where i am wrong)

Tags: python

```
number = int(input("Enter the number: "))

for i in range(1, number+1):
    print(sum(i))
```

#this where i left and pls tell where i am wrong

Comment: iterating, just `sum(range(...))`

Answer (score 0):

`sum(...)` can be used with an iterable:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(sum(numbers))
```

Using a for loop you have to save sum in a variable and store result into this

Example:

```
number = int(input("Number: "))
sum = 0
for i in range(1, number + 1):
    sum += i
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re code is wrong in that you’re using `sum(I)` for each item in the list. Each iteration, you’re trying to sum an int, not an iterable, `print(sum(1)), print(sum(2)), ..`

```py
number = 5
print(sum(range(number+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Before for loop, you have to create the variable `sum`, which adds and save the partial sum in every iteration:

```
sum=0 #initialize sum
for i in range(1, number+1):
    sum=sum+i # you have to add current i to the partial sum
    #you can use the contract form sum+=i for the line above
print(sum)
```